# Can't change keyboard shortcut on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, settings

In Settings - Keyboard I have added custom shortcut by press on +.

When I try to set shortcut I can't enter nothing. Why so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution. Firstly, I should delete desirable combination if it uses as shortcut in another command.

I found desirable combination on the list on Keyboard settings, then selected this field and pressed Backspace to reset combination from this command.

Now I can set desirable combination to my custom shortcut.

Comment: Yeah, apparently you have to remove the existing keyboard shortcut before you can attempt to enter it for a custom. What's crazy is that you try to update a non-custom (e.g. media keys) with an existing combination, it will prompt you if you want to remove the existing combination from the other shortcut to apply towards this one :(

Answer (score 1):

The procedure is indeed not very obvious on first time use. You observed that when you clicked +, the **Add Custom Shortcut** dialog appears. It contains the fields "Name", "Command" and "Shortcut".

- To set the shortcut, first click the "Shortcut" field, i.e., where it says *Set Shortcut ...*.
- The dialog now changes to show you a picture of a keyboard and the text *Enter the new shortcut*. Now press your desired keyboard combination. Once you do so, the keyboard combination will be filled in the "Shortcut" field.

To change the shortcut, click the little left-arrow with a cross in it on the right of the current shortcut combination. Now you can set a different combination the same way as above.

Comment: When I see keyboard and pressing desired combination, nothing happened. Keyboard still showing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is ergonomic. The behavior is: it expects you to click within the field at which point modifier keys will trigger an input capture.

If this is not what your issue is, then please describe your problem to me more and we'll work it out :)

Comment: From your answer I can't understand what I should do.